# HTML - Seeing more comment break all table

Tags: html

i make a page.Users see comments.
When they click "devam" url. They see more related to comment.

[image]

[image]

but this break the table. What i want is that it only changes the related comment width and height. how can i do that ?

Comment: your question is inexactly specified. If you need help, you will need to give us more details

Comment: What do you mean by "break the table"?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that it's expanding the cell and causing wrapping on the text of the other cells as well....use this style on the first two cells:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">...</td>
```

or, explicitly set a width to them i.e:

```
<td style="width:200px">...</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you searching for
http://jsbin.com/ejecij/2/edit

```
  <style>
      .date_col,.movie_col,.descr_col {
          height:50px;
      }
      .date_col{width:66px}
      .movie_col{width:100px}
      .descr_col{width:300px}

      .full_descr_col{
          width:300px;
          height:150px;
      }
  </style>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init_links();
    });

    function init_links() {

        $(".descr_col>a.fulltext").unbind().click(function() {
            $(this).parents("td").attr("class","full_descr_col");
            init_links();
        });
        $(".full_descr_col>a.fulltext").unbind().click(function() {
            $(this).parents("td").attr("class","descr_col");
            init_links();
        });

    }
</script>

<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td class="date_col">date</td>
        <td class="movie_col">movie</td>
        <td class="descr_col">description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date_col">date</td>
        <td class="movie_col">movie</td>
        <td class="descr_col">

            description

            <a href="#examplelink" class="fulltext">examplelink</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date_col">date</td>
        <td class="movie_col">movie</td>
        <td class="descr_col">description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date_col">date</td>
        <td class="movie_col">movie</td>
        <td class="descr_col">description</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```